# Poisson random variable, Central Limit Theorem

Tags: poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

A random sample of size $n = 64$ from a Poisson random variable with unknown
mean  yields a sample mean of $\bar{x} = 8.3$. Use the central limit theorem to find a$95\%$ condence interval for $\mu$.

I'm confuse on this problem.
Gives an $\bar{x}=8.3$ which is a sample mean.
after manipulating the CLT i came up with
$\bar{x}\pm t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}$

where $\bar{x}=8.3$, $n=64$, degrees of freedom $=63$, $t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=1.998$

How do I get $S$? is it equal to $\bar{x}$?

I thought i could come from the $poisson(64)\sim N(64, 8)$ with $S=8$ or

$\bar{x} \sim N(1, 1/64)$ with $S= \frac{1}{64}$

Any ideas of how to get $S$?

Am I even approaching the problem correctly?

Is it an Normal distribution and not a T distribution?

Comment: The statement such as "$\text{Poisson}(64) \sim N(64, 8)$" should be avoided.

Comment: The confidence interval "$\bar{x} \pm t_{\alpha/2}\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$" is valid only when the sample are drawn from ***normal*** distribution. It is incorrect to misuse this formula for a Poisson model. Meanwhile, it looks like that you need to review some basic concepts of statistics.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Which basic concepts do you recommend reviewing? I been reviewing the Poisson distribution a lot for this problem. The instructor advised to use the proportions idea used in class, but I still unclear as to how I get sigma, he advised that solving for mu is the long/complicated way to solve this problem. In any case, thanks for your help

Comment: I think reviewing Poisson random variable is useful for this problem. Moreover, you need to understand the principle of constructing confidence intervals, knowing that a single formula doesn't apply to every case. The basic principle is more important and useful than a symbolic equation. Also, I recommend you reviewing the difference between ***population parameter*** and ***sample statistics***.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $X_1, \ldots, X_n \text{ i.i.d. } \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$, then by classic CLT, it follows that 
$$\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i - n \mu}{\sqrt{n \mu}} \Rightarrow N(0, 1),$$
or equivalently,
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu)}{\sqrt{\mu}} \Rightarrow N(0, 1).$$
Based on this, when $n = 64$, an approximate $95\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$ can be obtained by solving 
$$\left|\frac{8(8.3 - \mu)}{\sqrt{\mu}}\right| \leq z_{0.975} = 1.96$$
for $\mu$ (the $t$ quantiles appeared in your attempt was unjustified). The result 
is $[7.62351,\, 9.03652]$.

Comment: is there another way to solve this without solving for $\mu$ for example we use the fact that $S^2 = \bar{X} = 8.3$ Hence $S= 2.88$ then I can use the formula i came up with. which gives the interval [7.5807,9.0192]

Comment: No one knows $S^2$, this is calculated from sample. $S^2 = \bar{X}$ is wrong.